# how to keep pandas.DataFrame column as pandas.DataFrame and not pandas.Series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

since .applymap() doesn't exist in Series, but in DataFrame, I'd like to keep my df['col'] as DataFrame.
I know that I could use .map() or .apply() [here a reference on topic]: [Pandas: change data type of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891038/pandas-change-data-type-of-columns)

But suppose I want to keep same methods name for code coherence... is there a way to force df['col'] to DataFrame ? AFAISI you could do :

```
pd.DataFrame(df['col']).applymap(isnan)
```

but it 2x slower than

```
df['col'].map(isnan)
```

that itself is FAR slower than

```
df['col'].apply(isnan)
```

is there no solution better than switching between .applymap and .apply() ?

Comment: A little unclear what you want, `applymap` is for a dataframe it doesn't make much sense to call `applymap` on a series when `apply` is specifically for this. You can get a df by using double square brackets: `pd.DataFrame(df[['col']]).applymap(isnan)`

Comment: Maybe you want: `df[['col']].isnull()` ?

Comment: what I'd would like was to use same function name for similar action on similar objects ! I still don't understand why we have Series.apply and DataFrame.applymap. But since I have huge respect for pandas devs (Wes in particuliar) I imagine there's a reason. Your answer (double square brackets 100% answers my question, thanks).